# Correct method for parsing string in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a string that is formatted like this:

```
C Aleksander Barkov C Nico Hischier UTIL Tyson Jost W Taylor Hall W Evgenii Dadonov W Kyle Palmieri D Kris Letang D Ryan Suter G Casey DeSmith
```

I need to isolate the names between each capitalized letter (and UTIL). 
The logic is to extract the content between each `capitalized letter` including the the word `UTIL`.

so that the final output is for example:

```
'Aleksander Barkov', 
'Nico Hischier', 
'Tyson Jost', 
'Taylor Hall', 
etc
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What is a 'name'? It may seem frivolous, but names are not standardized by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: It's the content between each capitalized letter.

Comment: Can you give the example output you are expecting?

Comment: 'Aleksander Barkov', 'Nico Hischier', 'Tyson Jost', 'Taylor Hall', etc...

Comment: Ideal solution would be to fix the data model to use a better format. You are wanting to make a split on a capitalized letter (C,W...) and a group of capitalized letters letters (UTIL). It looks like you will need to use regular expressions to do this.

Comment: Is this string a single column of a single row in a table? What are you going to do with it once you split it? Please provide some context.

Comment: What if someone lists "C" as their first name? I know a number of people who go by their middle names, and will just provide a first initial on forms. For example, Charlie John Smith who goes by "John" might list his name as  `C John Smith`

Comment: @JeremyJ., Yes, it is a string in a column. I'm going to save the the parsed names to a separate table in individual fields.

Comment: Since nobody's posted it yet, [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So grab a copy of [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/). Then you can do this:

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = 
'C Aleksander Barkov C Nico Hischier UTIL Tyson Jost W Taylor Hall W Evgenii Dadonov W Kyle Palmieri D Kris Letang D Ryan Suter G Casey DeSmith';

-- my solution works except for cases where the upper-case word is more than one char. You'll need to iron that out
SET @string = REPLACE(@string, 'UTIL', 'U');

-- solution
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, d.pos+2, d.nextPos-d.pos-3)
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    pos     = ng.position,
    nextPos = LEAD(ng.position,1,8000) OVER (ORDER BY ng.position)
  FROM   samd.ngrams8K(@string, 2) AS ng
  WHERE  ng.token COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '[A-Z] '
) AS d;
```

**Returns:**

```
name
------------------
Aleksander Barkov
Nico Hischier
Tyson Jost
Taylor Hall
Evgenii Dadonov
Kyle Palmieri
Kris Letang
Ryan Suter
Casey DeSmith
```

Note that, for cases where you have all-caps words with > 1 character you will have to update your logic.

**Update (Based on question in the comments):**

For a string formatted like this (note I dropped the final delimiter):
|Eri|Staal|Nico Hischier|Mitchell Marner|Taylor Hall|Kyle Palmieri|Jason Zucker|Ryan Suter|Will Butcher|Keith Kinkaid

You could refactor my query to look like this:

```
DECLARE 
  @string VARCHAR(8000) = '|Eri|Staal|Nico Hischier|Mitchell Marner|Taylor Hall|Kyle Palmieri|Jason Zucker|Ryan Suter|Will Butcher|Keith Kinkaid',
  @delimiter CHAR(1)    = '|';

SELECT 
  sortKey = ng.position, 
  [name]  = SUBSTRING
            (
              @string,
              ng.position+1,
              LEAD(ng.position,1,8000) OVER (ORDER BY ng.position)-ng.position-1
              --ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@string,ng.position+1),0),8000)-ng.position-1
            )
FROM  samd.NGrams8K(@string, 1) AS ng
WHERE token = @delimiter;
```

Note that the logic above uses `LEAD` which requires SQL Server 2012+ if you are on 2008 your would uncomment the line below it and remove the line the uses LEAD. Note, too, that this solution is a scaled down version of [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) (the 2008 solution) and [DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/) (the version that leverages LEAD).

All this said - *If you have control over the format why not store the records in [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)?*

Comment: I hope no one named "Resistance Is Futile" turns up in the list. `SET @string = REPLACE(@string, 'UTIL', 'U');` makes quick work of their name.

Comment: What if changed the formatting to something more uniform? Like this:


|Eri|Staal|Nico Hischier|Mitchell Marner|Taylor Hall|Kyle Palmieri|Jason Zucker|Ryan Suter|Will Butcher|Keith Kinkaid|

Comment: @AlanBurstein can you elaborate on Third Normal Form and how it applies here?

Comment: @AlanBurstein I would very much like to break this long string up into 9 separate values that I could store on an entirely different table. I'm just not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 4):

Just another option if you can't use Alan's solution via the nGram (+1)

First we perform a brute force replace creating a delimited string, then we parse this delimited string using a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'C Aleksander Barkov C Nico Hischier UTIL Tyson Jost W Taylor Hall W Evgenii Dadonov W Kyle Palmieri D Kris Letang D Ryan Suter G Casey DeSmith'

Select @S = ltrim(replace(' '+@S COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,C,'|'))  
 From (Select Top 26 C=' '+char(64+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)))+' ' From master..spt_values n1  
       Union All
       Select ' UTIL '   -- Note We add "UTIL" to the list
      )  A 

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(substring(@S,2,len(@S)),'|','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       Aleksander Barkov
2       Nico Hischier
3       Tyson Jost
4       Taylor Hall
5       Evgenii Dadonov
6       Kyle Palmieri
7       Kris Letang
8       Ryan Suter
9       Casey DeSmith
```

Comment: Great approach!